# Is the product of two Gaussian random variables also a Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Say I have $X \sim \mathcal N(a, b)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal N(c, d)$.  Is $XY$ also normally distributed?

Is the answer any different if we know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: For a negative answer to your first question, take X=Y, then XY=X^2 cannot be Gaussian since it only takes positive values

Comment: no: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html

Comment: how does this question related to this paper: http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf 
which says that "product and the convolution of Gauss
ian probability density functions (PDFs)
are also Gaussian functions".

Comment: @AsadIqbal They are related by a confusion between the product of some independent random variables and the product of their PDFs. A random variable product of two independent gaussian random variables is not gaussian except in some degenerate cases such as one random variable in the product being constant. A product of two gaussian PDFs is proportional to a gaussian PDF, always, trivially. Idem for the convolution of PDFs.

Comment: @Did suppose $x\sim N(0,1), y|x\sim N(e^x, cos^2(x))$ - the product of their pdf is not a gaussian...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As @Yemon Choi showed in the first question, without any hypothesis the answer is negative since $P(X^2<0)=0$ whereas $P(U<0)\neq 0$ if $U$ is Gaussian.

For the second question the answer is also no. Take $X$ and $Y$ two Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Since they have the same variance, $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ are independent Gaussian random variables. Put $Z:=\frac{X^2-Y^2}2=\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt 2}\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt 2}$. Then $Z$ is the product of two independent Gaussian, but the characteristic function of $Z$ is $\varphi_Z(t)=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$, which is not the characteristic function of a Gaussian.

Comment: This proves that there are cases where X and Y are independent and XY isn't Gaussian, and cases where X and Y are non-independent and XY isn't Gaussian. However, there is also the question of whether cases exist in which XY is Gaussian (which would mean that X and Y would have to be non-independent). It wouldn't surprise me if such cases did exist, especially if the joint density of X and Y is allowed to be a generalized function. (One also needs to rule out the pathological case where a Dirac delta function could be considered to be a Gaussian with zero variance.)

Comment: @jamaicanworm in an answer below I proved that this cannot happen when $X$ and $Y$ follow a bivariate normal distribution unless the variances are zeros.

Answer (score 171):

The product of two Gaussian random variables is distributed, in general, as a linear combination of two Chi-square random variables:

$$ XY \,=\, \frac{1}{4} (X+Y)^2 - \frac{1}{4}(X-Y)^2$$

Now, $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are Gaussian random variables, so that $(X+Y)^2$ and $(X-Y)^2$ are Chi-square distributed with 1 degree of freedom.

If $X$ and $Y$ are both zero-mean, then

$$ XY \sim c_1 Q - c_2 R$$

where $c_1=\frac{Var(X+Y)}{4}$, $c_2 = \frac{Var(X-Y)}{4}$ and $Q, R \sim \chi^2_1$ are central.

The variables $Q$ and $R$ are independent if and only if $Var(X) = Var(Y)$.

In general, $Q$ and $R$ are noncentral and dependent.

Comment: I am also working on the distribution of the inner-product of two random variables having a normal distribution. The different topics on the subject in this forum helped me a lot. Could you just give some references/proofs about your last sentence that the variables Q and R are independent if and only if Var(X)=Var(Y), cause I exactly faced this problem in my simulations (in signal processing applications). I could not understand empirically why my code was only working when Var(X)=Var(Y). Now it make sense with your last post.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I am stuck with finding the expectation of XY when both are gaussian distributed RV

Comment: thanks... what about the var(XY) ?

Comment: Random variables Q and R are independent if and only if (X+Y) and (X-Y) are. Now, these are linear functions of the vector (X,Y). It is a theorem in Multivariate Probability that two linear functions AU and BU of a Gaussian vector U are independent if an only if A.var(U).B^T = 0. This implies that (X+Y) and (X-Y) are independent if and only if Var(X) = Var(Y), as can be easily verified.

Comment: The independence of the differences is neat. Do you also have independence of $XY$ and $X^2$?

Comment: @UlissesBraga-Neto may I ask for a reference in multivariate theory where I can find this theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think this is valid since $\mathcal N(0,1)^2 \neq \mathcal N(0,1)\cdot \mathcal N(0,1)$. Think of the left hand side as sampling once and the right hand side as sampling twice. While of course for specific samples $x$ and $y$ the relationship $xy=\frac{1}{4}(x^2+2xy+y^2-y^2+2xy-y^2)$ holds, this corresponds to a single sample of $X$ and $Y$, while moving to $\chi^2$ corresponds to the dual sample case.

Answer (score 21):

As pointed out by Davide Giraudo, the characteristic function of Z is
$\varphi_Z (t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$. So, the corresponding probability density is given by:
$$\eqalignno{f_Z(z)&={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-itz}\varphi_Z(t)\,dt={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\cos zt-i\,{\rm sen}\  zt\over\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt\cr
&={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\cos zt\over\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt-{i\over2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{{\rm sen}\  zt\over\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt.}$$
The last of these integrals is null because the integrand is an odd function. Therefore,  ${\Im[f_Z(z)]=0}$ and we have
$$f_Z(z)={1\over\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}{\cos zt\over\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt.$$
For $z > 0$ this integral converges and represents *the zero order modified Bessel function of second species*, usually denoted as $K_{0}(z)$. Thus,
$$f_Z(z)={1\over\pi}K_0(|\,z\,|), \qquad |\,z\,|>0$$
This shows that the random variable $Z$ has a *K-form Bessel distribution*. For more information see, for instance, Johnson and Kotz. *Distributions in Statistics --- Continuous Univariate Distributi*ons. Boston, Houghton-Mifflin, 1970. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution.

Answer (score 20):

You can use moments to see that  the product $XY$
 of independent normals 
 cannot be normal except in trivial cases. By trivial, I mean $\mathbb{V}(X)\mathbb{V}(Y)=0.$

Suppose that $X,Y$ are independent normals so that $XY$ is normal.

**Case 1:** Suppose that  $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$. By independence, $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$, so $XY$ is mean zero normal, and hence
$$\mathbb{E}((XY)^4)=3\mathbb{E}((XY)^2)^2.$$ By independence we get
$$\mathbb{E}(X^4)\mathbb{E}(Y^4)=3\mathbb{E}(X^2)^2\mathbb{E}(Y^2)^2.$$
Either  $\mathbb{V}(X)=0$, or dividing by $\mathbb{E}(X^4)$ gives $ \mathbb{E}(Y^4)= \mathbb{E}(Y^2)^2.$
This shows that $Y^2$, and hence $Y$, has zero variance.

**Case 2:** Suppose that $\mathbb{E}(X^2)>0$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)>0$.  Then, without loss of generality, $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=1$.
In this case, we also have $\mathbb{E}((XY)^2)=1$, so 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(X^3)&=&\mathbb{E}(X)(3-2\mathbb{E}(X)^2)\\
\mathbb{E}(Y^3)&=&\mathbb{E}(Y)(3-2\mathbb{E}(Y)^2)\\
\mathbb{E}((XY)^3)&=&\mathbb{E}(XY)(3-2\mathbb{E}(XY)^2)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Subtracting the product of the first two lines from the third line gives 
$$0=6\mathbb{E}(X)\,\mathbb{E}(Y)\,\mathbb{V}(X)\,\mathbb{V}(Y).$$ 
Either we are in a trivial case, or back to Case 1.

Thus, the product cannot be normal except in trivial cases.

Answer (score 5):

For a general answer to your question please refer to the Wishart distribution.

Comment: I don't think so. Wishart is the product distribution of Gamma distributions. However the Normal distribution is not Gamma (Chi-Squared is), and the type of product taken here of Gamma distributions is a different one to the one meant in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer about using a Chi Squared doesn't seem helpful here since  and  are almost certainly noncentral and dependent. There is a note about using a [Normal Product Distribution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html) which seems highly relevant, though I haven't seen it in practice and is less flexible than what I propose. What I have seen performed is the [Delta Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) or [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) to estimate this distribution.

The Delta Method says that an arbitrary function of normals is also approximately normal and in your case the $Var(XY)\approx Var(X)\hat Y^2 + Var(Y)\hat X^2 + 2Cov(X,Y)\hat X \hat Y$ where $E(X) = \hat X$.

I have seen this used to compute the CI for a ratio of normals X/Y after taking a log transform.

Hope that helps others that stumble upon this as I have, but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In an answer above by @Davide Giraudo, it is shown that the product of two normally distributed RVs **does not necessarily** follow a normal distribution based on **a counterexample**. In another answer by @user940, for the independent case, it is proved that
the product of **any two independent** normally distributed  RVs **does not follow** a normal distribution. Here I extend this negative result for a more general case and show that the product of **any two  RVs with a bivariate normal distribution**, which can be **dependent**, **does not follow** a normal distribution.

Here, using the method detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4835511/1231520), I derived the characteristic function (CF) of $XY$ for a general case that $X$ and $Y$ jointly follow a bivariate normal distribution (can be dependent), which may be also useful for other purposes.

Let $X\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2), Y \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$, and $\sigma_{12}$ denote their covariance. Then, the CF is given by

$$\varphi_{XY}(t)=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{iA^2 C_1 t}{1-2iC_1 t}\right)}{(1-2iC_1 t)^{1/2}} \times \frac{\exp\left(\frac{-iB^2 C_2 t}{1+2iC_2 t}\right)}{(1+2iC_2 t)^{1/2}} $$

where

$$A=\frac{\mu_1+\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\mu_2}{\sqrt{2\left(\sigma_1^2+\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\sigma_{12} \right)}}, B=\frac{\mu_1-\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\mu_2}{\sqrt{2\left(\sigma_1^2-\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\sigma_{12} \right)}},
C_1= \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} \left(\frac{\sigma_1^2+\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\sigma_{12}}{2} \right), C_2= \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} \left( \frac{\sigma_1^2-\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}\sigma_{12}}{2} \right).$$

By comparing $\varphi_{XY}$ with the CF of a normal distribution, we realize that **these two become identical only for the degenerate case of** $\sigma_2^2=\sigma_1^2 \rightarrow 0$ (implying $\sigma_{12}\rightarrow 0$).