# Posterior distribution Question for normal

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$  form a random sample from a Normal distribution with
unknown mean $\mu$ and known variance $\sigma^2$, and the prior distribution of $\mu$ is a normal
distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$.

(a) Obtain the posterior distribution for $\sigma^2$.

(b) Show that if n is large then the posterior distribution of mu given that $X_i = x_i$, $(i = 1; ... ; n)$ will be approximately a normal distribution with mean $x_n$ and
variance $\sigma^2/n$.

Edit: I believe this question has to do with conjugate priors so feel free to steer me in the right direction if this is incorrect! Thanks beforehand.

Comment: In part (b), should the mean be $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$?

Comment: Yep it should be sorry!

Comment: And part (a) should be the posterior for $\mu$?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\text{posterior} \propto \text{likelihood} \times \text{prior},$$
and we know the likelihood and prior are both Gaussian [density functions]. Therefore, the posterior also follows a Gaussian density function. (Note that this is NOT the same as saying that the product of Gaussian random variables is Gaussian, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian).)

Part (a) can be done by writing out the density functions and multiplying them. Most of it is done [here (section 2.1-2.3)](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf).

For part (b), if you look at the expressions for the mean and variance of the posterior that you found in part (a), you will see that taking $n \to \infty$ gives you what you need.