# PDF of function of 2 independent Gaussian R.V's

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Assuming a r.v. $X​$  with pdf $N(0,σ_x^2)$​ and an independent r.v $Y​$ with pdf $N(0,σ_y^2)$​

for a set of positive constants $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma​$

what would be the distribution of  the r.v.

$$Z= \alpha X^2 + \beta XY + \gamma Y^2​$$

The problem is more complicated with nonzero means, so I would like to tackle it step by step

Comment: Notice that $X^2, XY, Y^2$ are all chi-square distributions. A sum of chi squares is chi square (might be non-central but is still chi square).

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda: Are you sure $XY$ is a chi-square distribution?

Comment: @Henry check the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda: So the answer seems to be no, but $XY$ might be related to the difference of two scaled $\chi^2$-distributed random variables

Comment: @Henry check the second answer (the one with 20-something points)

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda: That answer is what led me to say *"the difference of two scaled $\chi^2$-distributed random variables"*

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda , the distribution of $X^2$ and $Y^2$ is chi-square, but $XY$ has a K-distribution. The difficulty in getting the total distribution is that $X^2$ and $XY$ are dependent, same for $XY$ and $Y^2$