# expectation of product of two independent normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Say I have two normal independent random variables with nonzero means - X distributed as N(a,b) and Y as N(c,d). What is the mean of the product XY?

I see that the distribution has been computed ([Is the product of two Gaussian random variables also a Gaussian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian)) as a bessel function in an earlier question if it is 0 mean- but if the mean is not zero, is there a simple expression for E[XY] ?

Comment: Then the result is trivial: $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ under independence of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: I see - if it is not independent, and the correlation is some value say 'r', is there a simple expression?

Comment: Yes. Remember $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$.

Comment: got it. So it would just be the product + r

Comment: Almost. The general formula is $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] + r\sigma_X\sigma_Y$  [writing $\sigma_X:=\sqrt{Var(X)}$]