# Expectation of the product of two jointly Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

This is an extension to the previous popular [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683478/expectation-of-product-of-two-independent-normal-random-variables). Say I have two joint Gaussian random variables
$$
(Z_1,Z_2)\sim N(0,\Sigma),
$$
where $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. What the precise formula for $\mathbb{E}[Z_1Z_2]$? Thanks.

Comment: [Iserliss' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem). Also, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Notation_and_parameterization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb E\left[Z_1Z_2\right] = \text{Cov}\left[Z_1, Z_2\right] + \mathbb E\left[Z_1\right]\mathbb E\left[Z_2\right] = \Sigma_{1,2} + 0 = \Sigma_{1,2}$