# characterization of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

we have : 
a vector $z$ of dimension $n$.

a Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

a Vektor $d$ of dimension $n$.

and we are looking at

$$S = (z-Ad)^{T}(z-Ad)$$

is it possible to express $S$ as a Sum in terms of $z$ ?

best regards

edit :

we have a factor model with $k$ variables and $f$ factors.

my lecturer told me : $z$ has $\frac{k^2 -k}{2}$ entries and $d$ has $kf - \frac{f^2 -f}{2}$ entries (because $z$ is the vector of a symmetrix matrix, where we dont need the diagonal-entries and $d$ is the error-vector)

now he said we can express S as a sum of $$((k-f)^2 -(k+f))/2$$ summands, which are linear-combinations of $z$. (he mentioned the singular value decomposition of A).

Comment: What is $A$? I mean is it a special matrix?   $$S = z^{T} z-z^{T}Ad-d^{T}A^{T}z+d^{T}A^{T}Ad$$

Comment: $A$ comes out from a loading-matrix $L$ which is 'trapezial' matrix -- so i also think about special properties.. but lets assume we dont know something special about $A$ -- its just real and regular.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) The idea is : we should be able to write S as a linear combination of z, because z follows a normal distribution... and maybe we can write S as a sum of independent, squared normally distributed things -- maybe if we decompose the matrix A ?

Comment: Here, $A^T A$ is a symmetric matrix; it seems if you want to go further, we need to know more about matrices and vectors.

Comment: So the complete context is the minimization problem: $$S=(z−Ad)^{T}(z−Ad) \to min$$ should lead us to a generalization of the chi-square-distribution... we know z is normally distributed... so if S is a sum of squared normally distributed elements of z we are done.

Comment: Notice that, here based on your product: $Ad$ which has dimension $n \times 1$, then dimension of $z$ is $n \times 1$ and so this is a dot product; hence, your result is not a matrix!

Comment: hmmm - but do we get S as a sum of squared normally distributed z's ?

Comment: Here, you can write: $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{d}=\mathbf{w}$ then, $$(\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{w})^T(\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{w}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(z_k- w_k)^2,$$ do you mean this (it is based on the square of the ements of $\mathbf{z}$)?

Comment: thank you - but is it obvious that $(z_{k} -w_{k})$ is normally distributed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $S$ can be expressed as a sum of square normal variables if $z$ is normally distributed.

First, notice that $z^T A d = d^T A^T z$. To see this, define $v = Ad$ and note that

$$z^T v = \sum_{i=1}^n z_i v_i = v^T z$$

for any two vectors $z$ and $v$ of the same dimension $n$.

Then, using $v$ as defined above, we have

\begin{align}
S &= z^T z + v^T v - z^T v - v^T z \\ &= z^T z + v^T v \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( z_i^2 + v_i^2 \right),
\end{align}
which is indeed a sum of squared normal variables, since each $z_i$ is a normal variable. Note that each $v_i = \sum_{i=j}^n A_{ij} d_j$ is a deterministic variable. Then $S$ is a generalized chi-square variable.

I think some confusion about this question arises from the phrase "in terms of $z$". Perhaps you meant "in terms of the components of $z$"?

Another point of confusion might be the phrase "as a linear combination of $z$". To show that $S$ is a generalized chi-square variable, we wish to show that it is a [linear combination of chi-square variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution), which in this case are the squared components of $z$ rather than $z$ itself.

And to address Amin's concern that $S$ is not matrix, I believe the goal of the exercise was to show that $S$ is a *single* chi-square variable rather than a *matrix* of such variables, so the given expression for $S$ is indeed meaningful.

Also note that if $z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $w$ is a deterministic variable, then $z - w$ is also a normal variable, distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mu-w, \sigma^2)$, since expectation is a linear operator. However, $(z-w)^2$ is [not a normal variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian). So, $S$ isn't normal, but [this doesn't contradict the fact that it's chi-square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192807/pdf-of-the-square-of-a-standard-normal-random-variable).

Comment: Hello Justin Le and thanks for your answer. the vector $z$ is build of the non diagonal elements of $B^{1/2} X B^{1/2}$ where B is a covariance matrix, and X follows a normal distribution - therefore $z$ as well. The $d's$ are 'unkown' approximation errors - does it change the thing that S is generalized chi square distributed ? what can we say about the covariance matrix of $z$ ? maybe expressed with respect to $B$ ? best regards

Comment: and : the solution of the minimization problem must be $$d = (AA^{T})^{-1} A^{T}z$$... am i right?

Comment: added maybe something important in my main post