# Is the product of two Guassian quaternions a Gaussian quaternion?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, quaternions

Suppose we have $q_1\sim \mathcal N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $q_2\sim\mathcal N(\mu_2,\Sigma 2)$ two independent Gaussian Random Variables that represent two quaternions. Consider:
$$
q_3 = q_1\otimes q_2
$$

Is $q_3$ also a Gaussian Random Variable?

Comment: There's no reason to use the tensor symbol $\otimes$ for quaternion multiplication.

Comment: Note it's not even true for reals: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101062/11323

Comment: @arctictern a frustrating and confusing practice that started in the aerospace engineering literature. I appologize for the crimes of my people :-(