# Prove that XY is a chi-squared random variable if X and Y are independent normal random variables.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared

According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/397716/1231795),

> $X+Y$ and $X−Y$ are Gaussian random variables, so that $(X+Y)^2$ and $(X−Y)^2$ are Chi-square distributed with 1 degree of freedom, where $X\sim N(a,b)$ and $Y\sim N(c,d)$

I'm confused since while I understand that $(X+Y)$~Normal$(a + c, b + d)$ and $(X-Y)$~Normal$(a + c, b + d)$, I do not understand why $(X+Y)^2$ and $(X-Y)^2$ are chi-squared random variables.

As far as I know, only **squares of standard normal random variables** can be chi-squared distributed, and $(X+Y)^2$ and $(X-Y)^2$ are, in general, not standard normal random variables.

Am I misunderstanding / missing something here?

Comment: It is referring to the [generalised chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution).